# Confusion with tag "Georgia"

Tags: discussion, tags

As you know there are two Georgias: a state in USA and country. Consequently, the tag "Georgia" is used for both:

https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/georgia

I suggest changing one of them, or both, to avoid any confusion. For example:

- "**Republic of Georgia**"
- "**Georgia (country)**
- "**Georgia (USA)**"

Comment: Just for comparison, Travel.SE uses “georgia-country” and “georgia-usa”.

Answer (score 19):

Georgia, the US state, doesn't really need a tag (the one question using it that way was about a local election). Most states don't need a tag (CA being a notable exception, since they often use their singularly large economy for broader policy changes). Just use [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) to cover questions about it.

The existing tag should be renamed to [republic-of-georgia](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/republic-of-georgia), which denotes it's a country tag

Comment: Given the voting, I just went ahead and retagged the one question tagged that way (I had already retagged the US one). This is now done

Comment: I’m OK with the change, but (relevant for next time) I think you should have waited longer than a few hours before implementing it. Due to time zone differences and other things to do, not everyone who might have wanted to weigh in has had a chance. Two days seems appropriate to me.

Comment: @chirlu This can be easily undone if consensus changes

Comment: It's a single question we're talking about @chirlu. I personally wouldn't even have bothered with a meta question and would have just renamed it. No need to have a site-wide discussion about every little tag.

Answer (score 5):

Parenthesis are not allowed in tags. Only lower-case letters and hyphens.

I would consider sovereign countries to be generally more important than sub-divisions of countries. So I would suggest to keep using [georgia](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/georgia) for the country and create a new tag [georgia-usa](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/georgia-usa) for the US state.

Comment: I would change the name of both. Experience tells me people don't read the excerpt and just the tag name.

Comment: My experience with tags tells me that people simply note the tag exists. Excerpts are seldom read, and often omitted in mobile views of the site. Thus the tag itself has to be clear

Comment: @Machavity wrongly tagged questions can easily be corrected by retagging. That's easy if the excerpt properly state how to use the tag.